# google app engine generates long ids

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am working locally with windows 8 and latest version of GAE using python. after performing for one of my models model.put(), the generated id for this model in the datastore is 6088866696204910592L (i see it directly in the datastore and with model.key().id()).

from https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass#Key_id:

"id()
Returns the numeric ID of the data entity, as an integer, or None if the entity does not have a numeric ID."

does anyone have a clue why the generated id is sometimes not an integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the documentation: if you want to use Key.from_path you may pass "a string or a long" as the id_or_name argument. Maybe it just means "integer" as the opposite of decimal/float. As @Tim said, ints and longs are interchangeable in Python.

Comment: thanks Markon, you might have a point here :) anyway, if this is a documentation mistake i would be happy if someone from google app engine team would approve (as they announce stack overflow to be their new platform of Q&A).

Comment: now I see that the db.IntegerProperty can also be int or long (thanks a lot google...), so I guess you are right. thanks.

Comment: remember int/long are interchangeble in python so the documentation is correct.  They are telling you, it won't be a float and the id is numeric.